# ¿Acento en "que" en la siguiente frase: "No hay nada que agradecer"?

Tags: acentuación, cortesía

Sé que lo siguiente tiene acento en "que":

> "No hay de qué."

Pero ¿qué hay con estas variantes?

> "No hay de que agradecer."
>
> "No hay nada que agradecer."

Comment: Hay diferencias entre la pregunta (a la que quizás le vendría bien un verbo) y la segunda opción en el texto de la misma.

Comment: Buena pregunta pero me gustaba más antes de la adición de "nada"

Comment: Quiero decir que no tengo claro si preguntas si "que" debe llevar acento en **No hay nada que agradecer** (título de la pregunta) o en **No hay [nada] _de_ que agradecer** (cuerpo de la pregunta) o en ambas,

Answer (score 2):

Pues el del primer caso es un pronombre interrogativo o exclamativo, mientras que en el segundo caso tenemos un pronombre relativo.

En este segundo caso tenemos:

> *pron. relat. m., f. y n.* Introduce una oración relativa sin antecedente expreso. U. precedido del artículo determinado.

(2ª acepción de la RAE). Como ves es muy distinto al "qué" con tilde, que se trataría de (en su 9ª acepción)

> *pron. excl. n.* Pondera las cualidades de algo que no se expresa.

Sin embargo, quizá otras acepciones se adecuen más al uso que mencionas. Te recomiendo buscar ambas en DRAE, pues hay un conjunto muy prolijo de acepciones con ejemplos incluidos.

Comment: Gracias por señalarme la pauta.

Comment: No veo la conexion con lo interrogativo o exclamativo.

Answer (score 1):

La entrada del DRAE nos da

> [**que**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UkbUarn)
>   Escrito con acento en acepción 3.
>
> 2. *pronombre relativo masculino, femenino y neutro*. Introduce una oración relativa sin antecedente expreso. Usado precedido del artículo
>      determinado. *Visitamos las que recomendaban en la guía. Se fijaron en
>      el que estaba en el escaparate. Eso es lo que no entiendo.*
> 3. *pronombre relativo neutro*. Algo **que** o nada **que**, usado sin antecedente expreso, generalmente con los verbos *tener* y *haber*.
>      *Siempre hay qué comer en esta casa. No tiene qué leer.*

Es interesante este último ejemplo.  El acento nos ayuda a distinguir entre `No tiene qué leer` (se le acabaron los libros que trajo de la biblioteca) y `No tiene que leer` (no es forzoso que se ponga a leer en este moment).

Conclusiones:

"No hay de qué" y "No hay de qué agradecer" caen en la acepción 3.  (El mejor ejemplo dado para entender esto es "hay qué comer.")

Yo pienso que "No hay nada de qué agradecer" también cae en la 3, no más que ahora el antecedente sí es expreso.  (Sin embargo, creo que esta variante no se oye idiomática / natural.)